# "Google play App - signing issue" NoSuchAlgorithmException exception

Tags: java, android, google-play-console

while runing below command we get below error
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=encrypted_private_key_path --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=/path/to/encryption_public_key.pem

Unable to export or encrypt the private key
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding

We have latest idk 17 installed but issue coming with app signing

I read about bouncycastle to fix this but no idea how can install for mac or use it for idk 17 etc please help us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem,you should install OpenJDK 20.0.1[enter link description here](https://jdk.java.net/20/),and run the command again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76580388/the-private-key-was-not-properly-encrypted-or-is-not-a-type-of-key-we-support-w

can you help on this

Comment: Saved my day. Do you know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Please use open JDK 20 or later versions https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/20

Comment: This looks like the same answer as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76571400)