# The private key was not properly encrypted, or is not a type of key we support while generating app signing key

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-console

The private key was not properly encrypted, or is not a type of key we support .
I generated the play signing key on play console

```
$ java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=encrypted_private_key_path --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=/path/to/encryption_public_key.pem
```

I used above command to generate the key after generating it gives me error

```
The private key was not properly encrypted, or is not a type of key we support while generating app signing key
```

[image]

Comment: What is the signature used? `keytool -list -v -keystore foo.keystore -alias foo -storepass <your_keystore_password> | grep "Signature algorithm name"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android Studio App Bundle Signing Tool and create your private_key.pepk from there.

[image: App Bundle Signing]

Get your private key from the path you have added at the last Text Input area.

Comment: I tryed but get this error message on play console "The private key was not properly encrypted, or is not a type of key we support"